# A question about $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

The question says like this:

Let $S \subset [0,1]$ be a set satisfying the following two properties.(1)$0,1 \in S$;(2)For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and pairwise distinct numbers $s_{1},...,s_{n} \in S$ we have $\frac{s_{1}+...+s_{n}}{n} \in S$. Show that $S=\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$.

My thought just like this: I first write down $0,1$ and they generate $\frac{1}{2}$ and then ganerate $\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}}{2}=\frac{3}{4}$ and so on. I try to construct a triangel just like the following:

On nth row are numbers like $\frac{i}{n}$, $i$ from $0$ to $n$.

I want to use induction method. For the first line, we know that it is in the set $S$, I wany to prove that if nth row are in the set $s$,then the $(n+1)th$ row are also in $S$. I am stuck in this step. Can anyone help me with this stuck?

ps: I have another kind of induction proof now.I find that it firstly correct for all $2^{k}$ and once we had proved it, we can try to prove that if it works for $x$,then it also works for $x−1$, and finally we can prove taht it works for all natural numbers.

For $k=1$ we can know that it works for $2^{1}$, suppose that it works for $2^{k}$ then we can find that $\frac{0+\frac{1}{2^{k}}}{2}=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$ is in $S$ and do similar operations, we can prove that it works for $2^{k+1}$. What we left now is trying to prove that if it works for $x$,then it also works for $x−1$. And now, I stuck here.

ps:anyone who is also interested in this question can click into the "linked" question on the right side. And thanks to Mr. or Mrs. @SarveshRavichandranlyer 's comment which remind me that we can only prove that $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \subset S$.

Comment: To get equality, you need both inclusions $S\subseteq \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ and $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\subseteq S$ and your argument only seems to be one of these.

Comment: To try your induction proof, first figure out how to get $1/3$.  I think you will have to do $1/4, 3/4$ before you can do $1/3$.

Comment: @HSN ... notice "pairwise distinct" in the OP.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you, missed that somehow..

Comment: @GEdgar your words remind me that there is a proof of AM-GM inequality, which says that it firstly correct for all $2^{k}$ and once we had proved it, we can try to prove that if it works for $x$,then it also works for $x-1$, and finally we can prove taht it works for all natural numbers.I will have a try.

Comment: @HSN $S \subset \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is easy to prove, cuz rational field is closed for opeation additive and divide.

Comment: Regarding the second approach : see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2105537/show-that-s-mathbbq-cap-0-1?rq=1).

Comment: It is also not true that $S = \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$, because $T = [0,1]$ also satisfies all the above properties. You can only show that $S \supset \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranlyer I think $[0,1]$ can't be generated by $0$ and $1$，though T may satisfy all these properties.

Comment: @UESTCfresh The problem is the way the question is phrased. You see, IF the question is like this : I start from $0,1$ and take every possible fraction that is generated by taking the fraction $\frac{s_1+...+s_n}{n}$ for $s_1,...,s_n \in S$, then I cannot go beyond $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ by continuing to take averages unless I take something that is not an average of other elements. However, the question isn't phrased like that. It's phrased as "$S$ satisfies property 1 , property 2" : so as long as you find a set $S$ satisfying these conditions, you have a candidate.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranlyer Thank you for your comments. You remind me. I now also think that this exercise have some problems.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope the link is helpful eventually.

Comment: @Troposphere yes, it does.